# Different result from read() function when writing to int or char

Tags: c++, linux, unistd.h

I am using `read()` from `unistd.h` on a file descriptor. I need to read the first 4 bytes to an `int` variable and the rest to a `unsigned char` array.

So far, this does not work for getting the first 4 bytes:

```
unsigned int myInt = 0;
status = read (fd, &myInt, sizeof(myInt);
```

`read()` returns -1 and myInt stays 0.

reading to a char buffer however works:

```
char buf[512];
status = read (fd, buf, sizeof(buf);
```

`read()` correctly returns what it is in `fd`.

I checked, `unsinged int` is four bytes on my target.

What am I not seeing here?

EDIT: `errno` is **Broken pipe**. 
It's not a regular file I am reading from but a file descriptor made by gadgetfs to receive data from and send data to USB.

Comment: Does it work with this: char buf[4];?

Comment: Is it a normal file? Some devices have alignment requirements on read and write sizes and positions. And what's the value of `errno` after the failed read?

Comment: `errno` is **Broken pipe**. And no, it's not a regular file but a file descriptor made by gadgetfs to receive data from USB.

Comment: int should be aligned anyway, so the read should work if alignment were the problem.

Comment: I figured it out. I need to read all the bytes I am sending in one 'read()' call. My goal was to use 'read()' once for the first 4 bytes cause they contain the size of the following payload. and then call it another time for the payload. Any idea for a workaround?

Comment: In that case, something like "status = read (fd, (char*)&myInt, sizeof(myInt));" should work. Right?